# What does async / await do on IO operations?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

suppose sample snippet:

```
public async void writeDataOnFile (byte[] data, string filePath) {
   using(var fs = new FileStream(filePath)) {
      await File.WriteAsync(data,0,data.length);
   }
}
```

I know that no background thread is consumed from thread pool,but an IO operation will be started and thread will be notified at the end.

Question is: HOW does async/await understand that WriteAsync is an IO-bound method rather than a CPU-bound method?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The compiler doesn't need to understand that at all. It just schedules a continuation when the task returned by `File.WriteAsync` completes. *How* it completes is up to the implementation of `File.WriteAsync`.

Comment: For or more practical example on how tasks don’t care whether something is I/O or CPU bound maybe it helps if you take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh873178(v=vs.110).aspx#EAP where it shows a simple example how an event based action – download gets started and notifies when it’s finished – can be converted to a task. Something similar is done by WriteAsync where internally the OS notifies per callback when the operation finishes.

Comment: Also, "no background thread is consumed from thread pool".  I'm unsure about whether this statement is correct since I've never cared about the thread pool in particular, but I'm about 99% sure a background thread is *used*.  I feel like you may be inferring incorrect information from that statement, whether it's technically correct or not.  Not that `await` particularly cares about that either...

Comment: In my experience, it does tend to use a background thread, although you can limit the number of threads to 1 as I showed at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46892653/78162 if you're concerned about multiple threads encountering race conditions.

Comment: The question posed in the title is slightly different the the question posed in the body.  I believe others are answering based on the question in the body.  For the question in the title, the answer involves understanding [I/O Completion Ports (IOCP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198(v=vs.85).aspx), and how they relate to async/await.  [Stephen Cleary has a blog about that](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

Answer (score 3):

> Question is: HOW async/await understands that WriteAsync is an IO method rather than a CPU method?

The `await` keyword does not care whether it is IO or CPU bound. All it cares about is that the "call" is awaitable. Please see [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/01/13/await-anything/) for more details.

See this example below where the extension method returns a `TaskAwaiter`:

```
public static class ThisWorks
{
    public static System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter GetAwaiter(this Int32 millisecondsDue)
    {
        return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(millisecondsDue).GetAwaiter();
    }

    private static System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter GetAwaiter(this TimeSpan timeSpan)
    {
        return Task.Delay(timeSpan).GetAwaiter();
    }
}
```

Now to use that we can do this:

```
await 15;
```

There are better examples but at least this shows the point.